# Variável local ou método não definido

Tags: ruby

Estou com um exercício de Ruby onde tenho funções para fazer um simples jogo de adivinhação com número inteiro.
Após implementar a função 'pede_um_numero' passando os parâmetros, está dando erro ao compilar nas linhas 30, 31 e 17 onde aponta a variável 'tentativa' como não definida localmente ou método. **(maior_ou_menor.rb:17:in `pede_um_numero': undefined local variable or method`tentativa' for main:Object (NameError))**

Dei uma olhada no código procurando por erros de digitação mas sem sucesso, tentei arrumar a indentação do código, também sem sucesso. É minha primeira vez mexendo com Ruby, segue o trecho do código.

EDIT com o código inteiro para melhor entendimento.

```
def da_boas_vindas
    puts "Bem vindo ao jogo da adivinhação"
    puts "Qual é seu nome?"
    nome = gets
    puts "\n\n Começaremos o jogo para você " + nome
end

def sorteia_numero_secreto
    puts "\nEscolhendo um número entre 0 e 200..."
    sorteado = 175
    puts "Escolhido... que tal adivinhar hoje nosso número secreto?\n\n"
    sorteado #return sorteado
end


def pede_um_numero(tentativa, limite_de_tentativas)
    puts "Tentativa " + tentativa.to_s + " de " + limite_de_tentativas.to_s
    puts "Entre com um número"
    chute = gets
    puts "Será que acertou? Você chutou " + chute
    chute
end


da_boas_vindas
numero_secreto = sorteia_numero_secreto

limite_de_tentativas = 5

for tentativa in 1..limite_de_tentativas
    chute = pede_um_numero(tentativa, limite_de_tentativas)

    acertou = numero_secreto == chute.to_i

    if acertou
        puts "Acertou!"
        break
    else
        maior = numero_secreto > chute.to_i
        if maior
            puts "O número secreto é maior!"
        else
            puts "O número secreto é menor!"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVIDO.**

O editor de texto que eu estava utilizando aparentemente era o problema, troquei de editor e o código compilou e rodou sem nenhuma alteração.
Infelizmente não posso responder exatamente qual era o problema pois até o momento não descobri, apenas desconfio que o editor usado anteriormente não estava reconhecendo '(tentativa, limite_de_tentativas)' como variáveis